# Spring boot project Does not recognize Spring boot starter Beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i have created a spring boot 3 starter with an entity & it's repository : https://github.com/Boukhta-Ali/demostarter

then i tried to import the starter in a spring boot project by injecting the repository in userService class : https://github.com/Boukhta-Ali/spring3demo

while running the app, i got the error:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field userRepository in com.example.spring3demo.service.UserService required a bean of type 'com.example.demostarter.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

i tried to run the simple app with no errors

Comment: it seems like org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports file did not apply correctly

Answer (score 1):

By default Spring Boot Application will scan for components (beans) in the package were the configuration is defined and in all subpackages. In your case it is **com.example.spring3demo**.
But the UserRepository class is defined in a different package  **com.example.demostarter.repository**.

**Solution 1:**

Add an annotation defining a base package to be **com.example**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
public class Spring3DemoApplication {
```

**Solution 2:**

Move your *Spring3DemoApplication* class to the package com.example. Then you will not even need the above annotation.

Comment: Hello Mar-Z, thanks for answering, this will work but it's likely a workaround solution, for example while importing spring boot starters we dont have to add a @componentScan to scan spring boot packages

Comment: You wouldn't need this annotation if the main class were in the same package tree. But in your code the main application class Spring3DemoApplication is in a different package tree com.example.spring3demo. In this case the annotation with basePackages attibute is needed. Of course you could also move your class to the common package tree like com.example.